# How can I determine what application is asking "Where is GrowlHelperApp.App?"

Tags: macos, growl

I recently upgraded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks and am now seeing a "Choose Application" dialog pop up every minute or two asking: "Where is the GrowlHelperApp.app?". I don't particularly want to buy the new version of Growl, so how can I determine which application is looking for it so that I can change it's preferences or remove it?

[image: Choose Application dialog: Where is GrowlHelperApp.app?]

Update: It turns out that it was an old Dashboard widget that was looking for Growl. I found this out by deleting all of my Dashboard widgets since I haven't used it in a while, but I'd still be interested in finding out how one would discover what is launching this dialog.

Comment: What apps are running when this pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have used `sudo opensnoop` to see what files are being opened or [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) to see what files are being modified.

Those dialogs are often shown by AppleScripts that have reference a missing application. You could also have tried running `mdfind GrowlHelperApp`, but it doesn't search the contents of compiled scripts or scripts saved as applications.

Answer (score 1):

Helped me solve this problem I am having an awful lot of time. The `mdfind GrowlHelperApp` with combo of deleteting the resource files found helped me to remove the annoying popup window. In my case, Firefox was the rooting problem app.